# Error 1248 (42000): Every derived table must have its own alias

Tags: mysql

How come I keep the Error 1248 (42000): Every derived table must have its own alias? I've given each table it's own alias haven't I? Sorry I'm not too sure what I'm doing wrong here since I'm in my first semester for MySQL.

```
SELECT p.PlayerAlias as "Player", 
       s.HiScore as "Score" 
  FROM Player as p INNER JOIN Score as s ON p.PlayerID = s.PlayerID 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN (
           SELECT g.GameID 
             FROM Game as g 
            WHERE g.GameName = "Reaper"
       ) ON s.GameID = g.GameID 
 WHERE s.HiScore < 7000 AND s.HiScore > 4000;
```

Comment: `) ON s.GameID = g.GameID` should become `) as g ON s.GameID = g.GameID `

Comment: In the error _derived_ table is referring to your subquery.

Comment: Its amusing. I wrote the answer first and the acceptance is awarded to some one else.!

Comment: @FallAndLearn It was still giving me the error with your answer, his answer worked for me. Sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are missing an alias on the inner query right after the LEFT OUTER JOIN

```
SELECT p.PlayerAlias as "Player", 
       s.HiScore as "Score" 
  FROM Player as p INNER JOIN Score as s ON p.PlayerID = s.PlayerID 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN (
           SELECT g.GameID 
             FROM Game as g 
            WHERE g.GameName = "Reaper"
       ) as g ON s.GameID = g.GameID 
 WHERE s.HiScore < 7000 AND s.HiScore > 4000;
```

Comment: Its amusing. I wrote the answer first and you got the acceptance.

Comment: Thanks. Appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your subquery below should have an alias.

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
           SELECT g.GameID 
             FROM Game as g 
            WHERE g.GameName = "Reaper"
       ) AS T
```